# How to manage stock in multi store website in Magento 2?

Tags: magento-2.1, stock, manage-stock

I am using Magento 2.1.4

I have created 11 website each with 2 or 3 store view in Magento under same admin.

Now I want to enable "Manage Stock" options only for two websites. but it seems that this option in only visible in "Default Config" not in particular website or store views. Please refer below screenshot

Particular store view:

[image]

Particular Website:

[image]

Default Config:

[image]

When I enabled this option in Default config then it affected all websites and store views but I don't want that. So how can I enable this option only for two websites?

Comment: Have you got any solution?

Comment: IIRC stock settings used to be global before [MSI was introduced](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/inventory/). You may have to upgrade to 2.3 so you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you want multiple inventory management for all your stores. This option is newly added to Magento 2.3 onwards. You might need to upgrade your Magento to 2.3.

Check the following link:

https://magento.com/blog/magento-news/magento-2.3-new-tools-fuel-your-growth-2019